Making a Tikz Node/Pic have variable height with SVG border
I am making a character sheet for DnD, and want to have a bit more flair than just a rectangle box. I have SVGs of all the containers I want to use to box out the different sections. For the things that have very predictable contents, like ability modifiers and such, I can just define a pic that has a static size background picture, and be fine.
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twopage]{book} % 148*210mm, Textblock is 120mm wide, 190 long
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}
\usepackage[left=10mm,right=10mm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry}

%Static Size Picture
\tikzset{
   % Stat Block
   pics/stat/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4}{
   code={
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (Box){\includesvg[width=2.7cm]{Attribute}};
      \node[inner sep=0pt,above=-6mm of Box] (Name){#1};
      \node[inner sep=0pt,above=-17mm of Box] (Score){\HUGE #2};
      \node[inner sep=0pt,above=-28mm of Box] (Mod){\LARGE #3};
      \node[inner sep=0pt,above=-40mm of Box](SaveBox) {\includesvg[width=2.7cm,height=1cm,distort=true]{BondsIdeals}};
      \node[inner sep=0pt,above=-7mm of SaveBox,text width=2.3cm](save){\LARGE Save:\hfill #4};
      }},
}


\begin{document}
%Stats/Skills Page
\newpage
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, thick] (0,0) rectangle (12,19); %Bounding Box

\path (1.3/2+0.5*2.7+0*1.3,17) pic {stat=Strength/19/4/6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


But other things, like character abilities, will have varying heights, due to the differing amounts of text to include, and I would like to not have to set them individually. Is there a way I can make the SVG height variable, or some equivalent effect, like SVG2Tikz (that I am not understanding how to use) or similar? Additionally, help automatically placing them to not overlap would be great, since as I understand it pics don't get anchors like nodes do, so I cannot do relative references.

Can you complete your code so people can compile it to test? pics are not anchors but you can define points in them which you can then use later. This was broken, but I think it works now. The manual has an example. Alternatively or also, you can put them inside a local scope which you can name and then refer to. So you can get size etc. Note that asking multiple things in a single question doesn't work terribly well here. You should probably ask separate questions and link them as they're related. But providing usable code is still key.

@cfr I don't know what you mean by "works now", as I have changed nothing? I have listed the code as given to just define a static size pic, I felt that adding in a \tikzpicture environment placing one below would have been too verbose.
I also feel the two questions here are highly related, as I am wanting to automatically place variable height "pic boxes" for lack of a more correct term, and want to avoid the manual placing if possible.

An example should start with \documentclass{}, load whatever packages etc. are needed and provide code which can be compiled in \begin{document} ... \end{document} so that people can copy, paste and compile your code to reproduce the issue. What I meant by 'work now' was obviously not very clear. I meant that the creation of references inside the pic, as documented in the manual, now works I think. I said it because it didn't used to work at all and, though I believe it has been fixed, I haven't actually tested it. The local scope naming always worked.

One reason your questions might be better split is that people may know how to answer one but not the other. That means they aren't likely to answer. Fine if somebody happens along who knows both. Less happy if everyone is in the only-one-bit camp. But providing code people can compile helps regardless. Aside from anything else, it helps people who may not know how to make your snippet compile. And it avoids duplicating efforts.
